# Heatmap with ggbump plots - color coding number of paths taken

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Good Morning,
The aim of this plot exercise is to have a [ggbump style plot] (https://github.com/davidsjoberg/ggbump) but with many people travelling along the route from the entry to exit nodes. E.g., imagine each node (rows in the plot) are cities and we want to see how many people take each route along possible paths from the entry to exit nodes. Therefore, this would be a modification of the ggbump figure, but with darker colours for the paths taken more often.

An example can be seen in the following data, imagining there are 10 possible cities (integers 1:10) and people can make 4 stops along the way (cols 2:5). Col1 = user ID.

So if we had 100 people (rows), and here I have made only 5 possible paths to reduce the computational complexity thanks to a comment below by @tjebo. The data would look as following:

```
set.seed(123)  # set seed to ensure reproducibility
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 100))
# assign column names to the data frame
colnames(df) <- c("User ID", "Stop 1", "Stop 2", "Stop 3", "Stop 4")

# create a list of vectors representing the 5 possible paths thanks to @tjebo's comment
paths <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(4, 4, 4, 3), c(3, 3, 2, 4), c(1, 3, 4, 2), c(1, 4, 2, 1))

# create a vector of frequencies for each path
path_frequencies <- c(50, 30, 10, 5, 5)

# loop through each row of the data frame
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  # assign the user ID for the current row
  df[i, "User ID"] <- i
  # generate a random sample of integers from 1 to 5 based on the path frequencies
  sample <- sample(1:5, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = path_frequencies / sum(path_frequencies))
  # select the path corresponding to the chosen integer
  path <- paths[[sample]]
  # assign the path to the remaining columns of the current row
  df[i, 2:5] <- path
}
```

Then we would need to modify the following ggbump code to set the aes() as darker / thicker lines based on how many people to that route (similar to lavaan plot paths). Depending on the solution, might need to change format before plotting. (group_by then mutate.)

```
ggplot(df, aes(each stop, city (1:10), color = density function for path usage)) +
    geom_bump()
```

Perhaps writing a seperate function to count how many times each possible path is plotted, then pass this to ggplot as an index of the line opacity?

Kind Regards
Conal

Comment: What is your question? When you run your code, what is failing?

Comment: Thanks @PavoDive, what I would like to do is add a density/heatmap function to the lines in the geom_bump. So that they are quite faint for the paths that are not travelled often, and strong and bold for the paths travelled often. e.g., if 100 people go 1 -> 1-> 1 -> 1 then this line should be very strong. If only 1 or 2 people go 1 -> 2 -> 2- > 3 then this should be very faint. My question here was around how to approach this plotting problem. I wish I was at the stage where the code was failing, but do not know how to go about this issue.

Comment: I think although your idea seems nice, it does not make much sense in that particular setting. There are too many possible combinations! Look at your sample data, of the 100 IDs, there are 99 different paths. This is (1) computationally quite intense, (2) will not give a clear visualisation and (2) you will have only one line sticking out a little bit, because it is used twice instead of once.

Comment: Thanks @tjebo, great point about the complexity. I have changed the original simulated data code to drastically reduce this complexity. Now there are only 5 possible paths from 2:5, with substantial differences in their frequency. This I have set using path_frequencies <- c(50, 30, 10, 5, 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't think you were very far. It's not that difficult - you need to count your unique combinations (see below for one very easy way) and then you can use this count as a continuous aesthetic. In this case below, both line width and color represent the count.

Other comments in the code.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbump)

set.seed(123)  
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 100))

## I've changed the names to make coding easier
colnames(df) <- c("UserID", paste0("Stop", 1:4))
paths <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4), c(4, 4, 4, 3), c(3, 3, 2, 4), c(1, 3, 4, 2), c(1, 4, 2, 1))
path_frequencies <- c(50, 30, 10, 5, 5)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[i, "UserID"] <- i
  sample <- sample(1:5, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = path_frequencies / sum(path_frequencies))
  path <- paths[[sample]]
  df[i, 2:5] <- path
}
## You need to shape long, but first you need to assign an identifying ID
## for each unique combination
## you can then use this count as continuous aesthetic for line width, color, etc 
df_long <- 
  df %>% 
  select(-UserID) %>%
  count(across(starts_with("stop"))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(- n) 
  
## I am using n as both line width and color aesthetic
## I find color easier to understand/quantify than line width. 
## you also need to specify the group
ggplot(df_long, aes(name, value, color = n, group = n)) +
  ## use the count as width
  geom_bump(aes(linewidth = n)) +
  ## just a random palette which I like in this case. There are plenty plenty
  scico::scale_colour_scico(palette = "acton", direction = -1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @tjebo for your solution. This works really well - your solution is also impressively clean. Much shorter than the version I was working with.